# Knowing whether mail has open or not in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am using `Ruby on Rails` for my project there I have one requirement.

following is the requirement.

I should send mail to users(gmail, yahoo, live, etc).
I need to know whether they have opened the **sent mail and read the mail or not**. Based on this I need to **display metrics**.

I tried with `ahoy_email` gem but No use.

Comment: *"No use"* - please be more specific.

Comment: What was the problem with `ahoy_email` ?   You should show how you used it and where it went wrong, and perhaps someone can help you fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah I have used ahoy_email and I configured it, everything works fine, I migrated it and when I sent mail from my local system record is creating in ahoy_messages table, but when recipient opens the mail the opened_at field not updating

Comment: Tagging `php` and `python` as well, even though your question specifically says `ruby`... removing spurious tags

Comment: If ahoy is using images to track opens, it may not work with gmail because of image caching

Comment: Is your local system reachable from the outside?

Comment: No @Stefan, Actually my problem is, I need to update opened_at attribute once I clicked on the mail(mean that read the mail), but it happen when I click link inside the mail.

Comment: @stefan, do you have any idea about ahoy_email?

Comment: @Veeru Ahoy Email inserts an image tag into the email. When opening the email, that image is fetched from your application server and Ahoy Email updates the corresponding `opened_at` attribute. Therefore, your system has to be reachable from the outside, i.e. from the recipient's email client. Otherwise the image can't be fetched and the attribute won't be updated.

Comment: Yes, but when I push the code into heroku and tried from heroku application still I it wont updating.

Comment: I know that this isn't an answer, but can you use Mandrill app? I love this service, you can send 12000 emails/month for free, they give you open rate and click rate, you can also use Mailchimp html templates for your emails and use variables for use in your transactional emails. I did an small app few days ago with mandrill and i'm really happy with the service and API that you can use to get a lot of info about your sends.

Comment: I would second using Mandrill, but if you want to diagnose your current issue, check that the 1px image ahoy_email inserts is present in the email (using Chrome's Web Inspector, etc.), and then check your Heroku logs to confirm the image URL request is being made.

Answer (score -1):

We use sendgrid for this exact purpose. It's easy to setup and will give you information on delivered, opened, clicked (on something inside the email), dropped, bounced, etc...